# Query with IN operator ignoring special characters with case insensitive

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Need to write a query in java for mongo collection.

Find List of strings (IN query) among collection ignoring special characters  with case insensitive.

```
String result = String.join("|", item.getList());
searchQuery.put("columnName", Pattern.compile(result, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
```

I am getting pattern error while string contains special characters

Comment: What special characters are you trying to ignore and what does that mean?   I understand the case insensitive requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pattern.quote()` to treat the items as literals:

```
String result = item.getList()
        .stream()
        .map(Pattern::quote)
        .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

Comment: Quote method is useful  but I need to filter by case insensitive, still I am getting error